# Running telerik reporting pdf generation in docker linux container

Tags: docker, .net-core, telerik-reporting, linux-containers

I have a report that is designed using **telerik reporting** library and **.net core 3.1**. I have to generate pdf file for it using following code:

```
var reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
var report = new Report1();
var reportSource = new InstanceReportSource()
            {
                ReportDocument = report,
            };
var deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable{ { "FontEmbedding", "Full" } };
var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, deviceInfo);
```

everything work fine when running on windows. but when running on **docker linux container** the generated pdf will have no text at all
I tried to install **fonts** and required libraries in container by following command

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig
RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated \ 
        libc6-dev \ 
        libgdiplus \ 
        libx11-dev \ 
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

but the problem still not fixed, see the following snippet

[image: this is sample generated pdf in linux container]

what am I missing?

Comment: Can the app generate PDFs on a standalone Ubuntu/Debian machine? I'd make sure the code works on Linux before introducing new variables.

Comment: hi @abdusco the same problem happens also on Ubuntu/ Debian machine

Comment: try to build from source : https://github.com/telerik/reporting-docs/blob/ffbf0ad90a901c4d3abe6bef252709af00f367b5/knowledge-base/how-to-build-and-Install-libgdiplus-linux.md

Comment: @LinPy same thing

Comment: Any updates regarding the issue?

Comment: Even though the fonts are not installed, they should be automatically substituted with the default Linux font, usually DejaVu Sans. Try render in "IMAGE" to see if the rendering works at all. Add a trace listener to the application and check the output for any exceptions. See https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/configuring-telerik-reproting-privatefonts and https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/pass-configuration-to-report-processor-in-asp-dot-net-core-without-rest-service for info on privateFonts and render with ReportProcessor using external IConfiguration.